# displaying french content with sifr3

Tags: sifr

displaying french content with sifr, can't seem to make this work.

I have sifr working perfectly but it wont disply any french characters  and its for a french website.

Would love some help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, was missing one of the embeds

Comment: That is the right answer, but if your text is in capitals how do you retain the accented characters? I noticed the text is rendered to be top aligned in it's containing element and the overflow isn't displaying which is why I can't anything. I don't have a solution for this yet do you?